# Keyboard blinks between UIPageVIewController pages

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview, uipageviewcontroller

I have simple UIPageController, each page contains UITextView. When I show the page I call becomeFirstResponder for the UITextView. But keyboard blinks, something (probably UIPageViewController) hides the keyboard when active page hides. Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just put invisible UIResponder below everything and call becomeResponder() for this object between pages switching:

```
private lazy var keyboardKeeper: UIView = {
    return UITextView()
}()
...
self.view.addSubview(self.keyboardKeeper)
...
self.keyboardKeeper.becomeFirstResponder()
```

The hack, but works perfectly.